# Why doesn't IList support AddRange

Tags: c#, .net, ilist

`List.AddRange()` exists, but `IList.AddRange()` doesn't.
This strikes me as odd. What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Because an interface shoud be easy to implement and not contain "everything but the kitchen". If you add `AddRange` you should then add `InsertRange` and `RemoveRange` (for symmetry). A better question would be why there aren't extension methods for the `IList<T>` interface similar to the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. (extension methods for in-place `Sort`, `BinarySearch`, ... would be useful)

Comment: Also, they are very easy (I'd say, trivial) to implement yourself, which makes it a low-value feature.

Comment: @ShdNx They aren't very trivial to implement performance-wise. An "internal" `AddRange/RemoveRange/InsertRange` can work directly on the "internal" collection and optimize the `Capacity` management and use methods like `Array.Copy` to move around blocks of data. An extension method `RemoveRange` would probably be an order of magniture slower than `List.RemoveRange`

Comment: It's too bad there wasn't (and still isn't) any way for an interface (e.g. `IFoo`) declaration to specify a "helper" namespace (e.g. `MyAssembly`) such that if a class claims to implement `IFoo` but lacks method `int Bar(String)`, the compiler would auto-generate method `int IFoo.Bar(String p1) {return MyAssembly.ClassHelpers.IFoo.Bar(this, p1);}`  Had such a feature existed, interfaces could have included more methods like `AddRange` which could be implemented in terms of a base behavior, but which some implementatiosn could optimize.

Comment: They could be implemented as extension methods, that way the interface implementation wouldn't have to implement them. Why aren't they?

Comment: This makes no sense.  An interface abstracts an implementation, so that there can be multiple implementations of the same basic features; there's no reason why features should be omitted from an interface, because the "implementation is hard".  Without methods like "AddRange" on the interface, there is no guarantee the underlying object supports them, and at that point you're forced to either implement a sub-optimal extension or defeat the purpose of using an interface by making dangerous assumptions trying to cast to a specific implementing class.  Dumbed-down interfaces are over-used.

Comment: Agreed @Triynko -- I was just burned by missing `GetRange` on this interface and the lesson I learned is to not trust that inheriting an interface actually guarantees implementation. It would make more sense to me to move these to extension methods as mentioned earlier and not undermine the integrity of the interface contract.

Comment: There should be the IRangeList interface supporting bulk operations, implemented only on some collections which internally will have the implementation optimal.

Comment: You can inherit IList<T> and add it and use it.

Comment: I don't think that this is a particularly good answer, but it does hit at the issue. An interface does not have to be 'easy' to implement, but should cover the necessary functionality that a class should implement. Better would be, as has been mentioned in other answers, that the List<T> should implement further interfaces such as an additional 'ISupportsAddRangeList<T>', which could be implemented, as required. The 'symmetry' mentioned is all fine and good, but also hints at further interfaces, as they may not be required in all scenarios.

Answer (score 18):

For those who want to have extension methods for "AddRange", "Sort", ... on IList,

Below is the `AddRange` extension method:

```
 public static void AddRange<T>(this IList<T> source, IEnumerable<T> newList)
 {
     if (source == null)
     {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
     }

     if (newList == null)
     {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newList));
     }

     if (source is List<T> concreteList)
     {
        concreteList.AddRange(newList);
        return;
     }

     foreach (var element in newList)
     {
        source.Add(element);
     }
}
```

I created a small library that does this. I find it more practical than having to redo its extension methods on each project.

Some methods are slower than List but they do the job.

Here is the GitHub to interest them:

[IListExtension repository](https://github.com/Emilien-M/IListExtension)

Comment: Why not use `this ICollection<T> source` instead of `this IList<T> source`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, nobody, except `.Net platfom` developers and architects, can answer this question. But there are few points, which could be reasons.

In this answer, I will speak about non-generic classes, but almost all my words will be right also for generic ones.

Before I move to the explanation, I'd like to mention for those, who don't know, `List<>` and all `IList` implementations **is not** supposed to be a [*List*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)) in terms of common programming and data structures, that is usually mean *linked list*. And in the [Microsoft Documentation of IList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=netframework-4.8) we can see definition

> Represents a collection of objects that can be individually **accessed** by index.

So, generally, reading this definition, you mustn't have a question about "Why `AddRange` is not presented in `IList`", but "Why `Add` is presented?". And, speaking about `Add`, it is not in the `IList` interface, but in the `ICollection` interface. And this isa really weird thing. Why? Because almost all collections in the .Net Standard inherit `ICollection`. And because of this there are many places in .Net source code, where we can see `Add` implementation like in the [Array](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/array.cs) class (Yes, `Array` implements `IList` also):

```cs
int IList.Add(Object value)
{
   throw new NotSupportedException(Environment.GetResourceString("NotSupported_FixedSizeCollection"));
}
```

There are more things, that I can say about relations between collections interfaces in C#(also about [IReadOnlyList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=net-6.0), that was added much after `IList` and looks like thing, that `IList` supposed to be). But I think there is enough context, and we can start speaking about concrete reasons why `IList` has no `AddRange`, but `List<>` has.

- ##### Not all `IList` implementations supposed to have `AddRange` method.

  As I mentioned above, there is a problem with `Add` method. A lot of collection in C# actually have it, but throws `NotSupportedException`, when it's called. And the same situation(even worse) would be with `AddRange` method. So only `List<>` need this method, but all other implementations of `IList` don't need it. Moreover, those developers, who decide to create their own implementation of `IList` will have to implement `AddRange`, that doesn't look like thing, that is really need for simple indexed collection(which is the `IList`).
- ##### `AddRange` is strongly dependent on `List<T>` implementation.

  Speaking about [`List<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) class. The is no non-generic class called `List`. Non-generic variant is called [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0). And `ArrayList` is some kind of synonym of [*Dynamic Array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) in terms of data structures. I don't know why it was decided to rename `ArrayList` to `List` in generic collections, but I think it just increases misunderstanding about these classes in C#. So, `List<T>` is a dynamic array in fact. And dynamic array would have big performance problems if you will add large count of elements to it one by one. So `AddRange` is an auxiliary and, in a sense, necessary method for dynamic array. But it is completely not necessary for indexed collection, which is the `IList`.

As a conclusion, I want to say, that `List<T>` and `IList<T>`(just like `ArrayList` and `IList`), in fact, are entities, that have different semantic, and you mustn't look at them like something interchangeable. But there are some bad decisions with naming and interface relations, that have been made and led to the growing misunderstanding of relation between `List<T>` and `IList<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Since C#7 we have pattern matching which we can easily use to call the more performant `List.AddRange()` method and do not need to use the `as` save cast.

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    if (collection is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));
    if (items is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));

    switch (collection)
    {
        case List<T> list:
            list.AddRange(items);
            break;
        default:
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                collection.Add(item);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```